# How to call a .NET xml webservice from Sinatra?

Tags: sinatra

I have a .Net XML webservice that I need a simple Sinatra app to call.  Really it's just forwarding it.  Say I have my sinatra.myapp.com/mywebservice.asmx catch the request, and then throw it to www.myoldapp.com/mywebservice.asmx with all of the incoming parameters, get the response and then have sinatra.myapp.com return the results to the client.

Domain aliasing is unavailable to us in this scenario, as is trusting that the consumer of the sinatra.myapp.com endpoint is capable of following redirects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how I would have done it:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'net/http'
require 'rexml/document'

get '/mywebservice.asmx' do
  query_string = ''
  params.each  { |k, v| query_string += k + '=' + v + '&' }

  http     = Net::HTTP.new('www.myoldapp.com', 80)
  response = http.get('mywebservice.asmx?' + query_string)

  xml      = REXML::Document.new(response.body)
end
```

You can now do whatever you want with the REXML object.
I can't tell you much about how to use it because I don't master it myself, but you can find many resources on the Internet that talk about it.

Comment: I ended up switching to Rails because I could not for the life of me get access to params (was {}) on a post version of this